# Learning material on SAT (Boolean Satisfiability Problem)

Tags: computer-science, sat-solvers

What are good documents to read on SAT (Boolean satisfiability problem) solvers. I have not been able to find good material via Google. The documents I found were either birds eye view, too advanced or corrupted PDF files...

Which papers/documents do you recommend to learn about the algorithms in modern practical SAT solvers?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "solving SAT questions"? SAT questions are specifically designed so that the test taker needs to have creative problem solving skills. A computer does not have this.

Comment: Cory, he means satisfaction problems in Boolean logic (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem), not questions on the SAT (one set of college entrance exams widely used in the US).

Comment: Yes, sorry, Doug McClean is right: my question is about boolean satisfiability solvers.

Comment: Check out the documentation on minisat, they have a paper detailing their approach. Very readable and thorough.

Comment: I've just recently written an article on SAT: [Boolean Satisfiability Problem in 5 mins](http://0a.io/boolean-satisfiability-problem-or-sat-in-5-minutes/) Perhaps anyone who is new to it may find it useful. (it covers the classical DPLL algorithm and improvements that can be made on it [e.g. VSIDS introduced in chaff])

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Davis-Putnam-Logemann-Loveland page on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm) has a good overview.

Then you should be able to follow the minisat paper ["An Extensible SAT-solver"](http://minisat.se/Papers.html).

You should also read ["GRASP - A New Search Algorithm for Satisfiability"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.24.2512) to understand the conflict-driven learning algorithm used in minisat.

I was able to write a SAT solver in Python quite easily using those resources. My [sat.py](http://repo.or.cz/w/zeroinstall.git/blob/6d1376a79f93bb9446d0c8396bfa9f34b861d84d:/zeroinstall/injector/sat.py) code is available (LGPL 2.1 currently), but it's quite recent so may still contain bugs. It lacks a few optimisations from the minisat design; if you want raw speed use the minisat code ;-)

Update: I've also made an OCaml version, [sat.ml](https://github.com/0install/0install/blob/e89e2d6fe2c2cd4a5517892646f7ef2cab89494d/ocaml/support/sat.ml), which might make it easier to see the types.

Comment: Thanks. No PDF reader would open the files on the minisat website, so I gave up on these. But since you suggested them I assume that you *can* open them. And indeed when I open them with Google's online pdf viewer they *do* work! Thanks.

Is your Python SAT solver's code available?

Comment: Good idea - I've added a link to my code. The PDFs opened fine for me (in Evince: http://projects.gnome.org/evince/).

Answer (score 0):

A good Book is: Uwe Schöning; Jacobo Torán - The Satisfiability Problem